# Are the new Macbook Pro 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: mac, macbook

I just got a new Macbook Pro. I know it's an Intel processor, but is it 32 bits or 64 bits processor?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_64#Intel_64  It's highly unlikely that any mainstream desktop processors from Intel will not support 64-bit in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

64bit processor

Answer (score 7):

Enter this into Terminal:

```
uname -a
```

If you see

`x86_64`

at the end of the string returned , your OS X kernel suports 64 bit.

Also bear in mind you need to hold down the <kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>4</kbd> keys while booting to startup with the 64 bit kernel ( there are other ways to accomplish this as well )

At least this was the case on recent Macs - I assume the new MacBook Pros released in April 2010 still boot by default into 32 bit mode as well.

Comment: A 32-bit kernel doesn't prevent apps running in 64-bit mode - just look at Activity Monitor.

Comment: And in any case, even if the kernel is 32-bit, the processor can still be (and indeed, is) capable of 64-bit.

Comment: I don't see x86_64... this is mine:
Darwin Michael-Changs-MacBook-Pro.local 10.3.1 Darwin Kernel Version 10.3.1: Mon Mar 22 15:13:15 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.3.52~1/RELEASE_I386 i386


what does that mean?

Comment: Hi Mike .. if you've seeing I386 ...then your MacBook is booted into the 32 bit kernel.